# stop form from refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which accepts data from user , and gives a success message after sending a mail by calling a java service. After successful sending, user should get a success message. In my case the form is a pop - up. So on submitting the form posts the data and the popup refreshes / submits and no success pop up comes. 
I am using the below code:

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Mail Sent successfully" );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

But I dont want the above alert. I want my customized popup for success message, which is not an alert . For Example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  event.preventDefault();
});
});

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Mail Sent successfully</p>
</div>
```

which is not working.

I also tried, `return false` in script and

```
<form method= "post" onsubmit= "return false()">
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the `onsubmit` attribute for the form, not `onclick` since you will want to listen for the form being submitted, not clicked.

Comment: oops, my mistake...in actual code I have used onsubmit only, changed now in my question.

Comment: `<form method= "post" onsubmit= "return false()">` won't work as false is not a function, you need `<form method= "post" onsubmit= "return false">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing id="target" in form

```
<form method= "post" id="target">
  <input type="submit"/>  
</form>

<script>
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Here is demo https://jsbin.com/duyevo/edit?html,js,output